# Can I overcome cache coherence in coding?

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-cache

I know that cache coherence is the consistency of shared resource data that ends up stored in multiple local caches.

Can any programming languages handle this problem? If so, how?

Comment: "the ability to held the problem in programming languages" That doesn't actually make sense as an English sentence and I can't work out what you're trying to say. Perhaps if you edit the question to rephrase it or explain in a comment, we can work out what you're asking. (By the way, it soundsl ike your question is actually about programming techniques, which would be off-topic, here. But we can move the question somewhere more appropriate, if it needs that.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby: I proposed a reformulation.

Comment: What's the problem with caches that you wish to address?

Comment: Please, can you explain if that was your question? Try to give more details. Do not worry too much about your English syntax. You can write a comment or edit the question to give more details. - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -If you do not do it, your question may be closed, and it will not be possible to answer you.

Answer (score 2):

I am following the rephrasing of the question by Dave Clarke.

A first remark is that cache is an ubiquitous concept in computation. In
programming, you find it at many levels in programming systems. In the
computer you have registers that act as caches for the main memory,
main memory pages that are caches for the disk, and possibly disk
files that cache bulk storage outside the computer. When you analyse
[memory hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_hierarchy) used by modern systems, each level can often be seen
as a cache for the next level higher up.

At the low end, it can be even more refined in the processor structure.

At the high end, it also goes further, as caches (called proxies) are
being used to speed up internet exchanges. Not to mention the [NNTP
protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_News_Transfer_Protocol) for distributed information which may be seen as composed only of caches, the memory being the union
of all caches, much of the protocol being a form of cache coherence.

Of course, the importance of [cache coherence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence), and the way it is
implemented (or ignored) is dependent on the role of the cache, of the
context of concerned applications that make use of the cache
infrastructure, and their need for time of consistency accuracy.

A basic principle of caching is that it should be essentially invisible
to its user. Hence it is expected to be implemented rather in the
system that manages access to data rather than in the application
accessing the data.

I am not an expert, but I would think that cache coherence is ensure
by whatever manages the cache. At the smaller end, for registers, I
would guess it is managed by the hardware. For paging I would think it
is done by the OS kernel (but I am no system expert). An internet
cache will be managed by the system implementing the communication
protocol.

Programming languages can of course be used to implement cache
systems, including maintaining cache coherence. Probably not any
language. I would not use an interpreted language to handle low level
caches. Doing system programming in Prolog could be a dubious idea.

However, I do not see what it would mean for a programming language to
handle the problem for applications written in that language. The fact
that caching may be involved depends on what application the language
is used for, and how.